# userauth is returning cookie but when data is returned it is giving error 500

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, jwt, nestjs

```
 @Get('userauth')
  async userAuth(@Req() request: FastifyRequest) {
    
    const cookie = request.cookies['jwt'];
    try {
      const data = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(cookie);
      return data;
      // Rest of the code
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('JWT verification error:', error);
      // Handle the error appropriately
    }
      return cookie;
  }
```

I tried using logging error on consle it is returning
JWT verification error: JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed

Comment: Please explain what this has to do with Postgres, you do not seem to be connecting/accessing a database in this code fragment.